# Angular 4 setTimeout() with variable delay and wait

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of events with `timestamp`. 
What I want is to display the events based on the `timestamp`:

To add a delay:

```
delay = timestamp(t+1) - timstamp(t)
```

I know this doesn't work well with `setTimeout`, but there is an workaround, if the timeout is constant, in my case is not.

Is it possible to make the next `setTimeout()` wait for the previous one? To be specific, if the first `setTimeout()` has a 5 second delay and the second one has 3 seconds, the second one will appear first. I want them to be in the same order but execute one after the other.

This example works for a constant delay, but I want to calculate the delay based on the information I take iterating the list.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
  setDelay(i);
}

function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: If there are two times as you mentioned, do you want 5 to print first and then 3 to print 3 seconds after that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [**IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and function recursion instead. Like this:

```
let i = 0;
(function repeat(){
  if (++i > 5) return;
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Iteration: " + i);
    repeat();
  }, 5000);
})();
```

Live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ub7v9whe/).

Answer (score 6):

When using the latest Typescript or ES code, we can use aync/await for this.

```
let timestampDiffs = [3, 2, 4];

(async () => {
  for (let item of timestampDiffs) {
    await timeout(item * 1000);
    console.log('waited: ' + item);
  }
})();

function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

We need to wrap the for loop in an async immediately invoked function because to support await.

We also do need a timeout function that returns a promise once the timeout is complete.

After that, we wait for the timeout to complete before continuing with the loop.

Answer (score 5):

Don't call it within a loop, as it won't wait for the `setTimeout` to complete.

You can instead pass a list of times that you want to wait, and iterate them recursively:

```js
let waits = [5000, 3000, 1000];

function setDelay(times) {
  if (times.length > 0) {
    // Remove the first time from the array
    let wait = times.shift();
    console.log("Waiting", wait);
    
    // Wait for the given amount of time
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Waited ", wait);
        // Call the setDelay function again with the remaining times
        setDelay(times);
    }, wait);
  }
}

setDelay(waits);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set time out period  using i value dynamically. Like

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
  setDelay(i);
}

function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
  }, i*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of something like that:

```js
setDelay(1,5);

function setDelay(i, max) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
    if(i < max){
      i++;
      setDelay(i, max);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

The idea is to set the next `setTimeout(..` in a timeout.
Of course you can modify it to have different long timeouts as well.

Hope i can help :)