# Force other components to run (change) before my button's (mousedown)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formly

I have a button on formly with mousedown that has a method called "analyzeClick()"

```
<button *ngIf="show" (mousedown)="analyzeClick()" id={{htmlID}}>
  {{label}} 
</button>
```

now, we also have inputs that have
have a (change) event that runs a method called "saveData()"

```
<input id={{htmlID}} type="text" [formControl]="frmControl" (change)="saveData()"  />
```

However, we found that after you are typing on an input and immediately clicking on the button, (mousedown) runs first **before** (change)
and the problem is that the method on analyzeClick needs data on saveData..

I've tried applying a timeout as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110528/15277118)

```
public analyzeClick(): void {
        

        let i = 0;
        (() => {
            if (++i > 1) {
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('Iteration: ' + i);
            }, 15000);

            this.runTheCode();
        })();
}
```

but still, a button's (mousedown) runs first before an input's (change)

What do I need to do in this scenario to make sure an input's (change) runs first before (mousedown)??

Comment: wild guess as I'm not sure i totally undestand your problem (the saveData() and analyzeClick() methods are invoked by different HTML elements?): try injecting the angulars changeDetectorRef and call detectChanges() on the saveData() method.

Comment: @scy correct they are invoked by different html elements. Ok will try to look for reference for changeDetectorRef and detectChanges(), thansk for the clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 events to consider:

- `change`
- `input`
- `mousedown`
- `click`

`input` occurs immediately, so that is one way to be absolutely sure that your changes are seen.

`mousedown` occurs before `change` - so on your first mouse down, you won't get the entered value

`click` occurs after `change` - so that is also safe to use.

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-snyo2p?file=src/app/app.component.html) for example.

Comment: Much appreciated. We have resolved to use the (click) event instead which runs last after (change) events